# xcode 4.5 iOS Storyboard and UITableView delegate confusion

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I am trying to make a simple iOS application that uses a UINavigationController two ViewController and a UITableView to display a list. The problem is that the table refuses to display the data from NSArray. All delegates are setup as you see in the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Every thing works if i create a xib file for the ViewController, but i dont need one more xib file if i can drag one more ViewController in Storyboard and to link it's class to my ItemListViewController as you see in the first picture.

**ItemListViewController.h**

```
#import 

@interface ItemListViewController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableArray *tblDataSource;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;
}

@property (assign) NSMutableArray *tblDataSource;
@property (retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblSimpleTable;

@end
```

**ItemListViewController.m**

```
#import "ItemListViewController.h"

@interface ItemListViewController ()

@end

@implementation ItemListViewController

@synthesize tblDataSource,tblSimpleTable;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
    self.tblSimpleTable.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];

    NSArray * data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    [tblDataSource setArray:data];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"@%d",[tblDataSource count]);
    return [tblDataSource count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UIImage *placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    [cell.imageView setImage:placeholder];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tblDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Clicked on row @%d",indexPath.row);
}

@end
```

If someone could point me in the right direction what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `numberOfSectionsInTableView` you're returning 0, which says there are no sections to generate (and therefore no rows, either). You probably want to return 1.

Also, you want to make sure you retain your `NSMutableArray`, so you really want to do:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tblDataSource;
```

Comment: i return 1, and table anyway doesn't display nothing there.

Comment: Your answer were correct :) the problem was also the way i was adding elements in the datasource array :) [tblDataSource setArray:data]; was not working, so i changed it to tblDataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto",nil]; and it works :D Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and helping me to debug it.

Comment: @Constantine By the way, equivalent to what you've done, you could change the property to `retain` (and leave your creation of the array as it was). It's probably equivalent, but makes the proper memory management more explicit. Also, (since you're not using ARC) don't forget to define your `dealloc` method to release `tblDataSource`, so the array will be cleaned up when you're done.

Comment: And, just as a matter of style, when you `@synthesize` variables, it's no longer advised that you explicitly declare the class instance variables, too. `@synthesize` does that for you, and by leaving it to the compiler, you avoid the possibility of a typo that could leave you with extraneous ivars.

Comment: Thank you @Rob for all this hints :) memory management is the last part i was thinking while trying to make it to work :)

Comment: @Constantine Excellent. And if you forgive the observation, I'd heartily encourage you to contemplate shifting to Automatic Reference Counting, as it simplifies the memory management stuff. Go ahead and focus on your table view stuff for now (and master the art of manual memory management), but ARC eliminates the headaches of making sure you have all the right `autorelease` and `release` statements. It's not bad to do a test project or two using manual reference counting, but when you shift to ARC, you'll eventually find you spend less time worrying about that sort of stuff.